# Replacing all matches except if surrounded by or only if surrounded by

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

Given a text string (a markdown document) I need to achieve one of this two options:

- to replace all the matches of a particular expression (`(\W)(theWord)(\W)`) all across the document **EXCEPT** the matches that are inside a markdown image syntax `![Blah theWord blah](url)`.
- to replace all the matches of a particular expression (`{{([^}}]+)}}\[\[[^\]\]]+\]\]`) **ONLY** inside the markdown images, ie.: `![Blah {{theWord}}[[1234]] blah](url)`.

Both expressions are currently matching everything, no matter if inside the markdown image syntax or not, and I've already tried everything I could think.

[Here is an example of the first option](https://regex101.com/r/vM9cL6/1)

[And here is an example of the second option](https://regex101.com/r/yN7kA2/1)

Any help and/or clue will be highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Url should not contain spaces. So, the simplest way is remove them from the second patern

Comment: Actually, I need to do nothing with the url, the problem is to **avoid** the matches inside the `![...]` part for the first option... or get **only** those inside  that `![...]` part for the second one. I think it would be clear looking the posted examples.

Comment: Is the `![Blah` always starting its own line?

Comment: Yes, we assume it is, for sure.

Answer (score 2):

Well I modified first expression a little bit as I thought there are some extra capturing groups then made them by adding a *lookahead* trick:

-First one ([Live demo](https://regex101.com/r/fT7iH8/1)):

```
\b(vitae)\b(?![^[]*]\s*\()
```

-Second one ([Live demo](https://regex101.com/r/bE6gM4/1)):

```
{{([^}}]+)}}\[\[[^\]\]]+\]\](?=[^[]*]\s*\()
```

**Lookahead part explanations**:

```
(?!            # Starting a negative lookahead
    [^[]*]     # Everything that's between brackets
    \s*        # Any whitespace
    \(         # Check if it's followed by an opening parentheses  
)              # End of lookahead which confirms the whole expression doesn't match between brackets
```

`(?=` means a positive lookahead

Comment: Demo 1 needs `i` modifier. Nice solutions though.

Comment: These solutions are workarounds. If there is a stray square or round bracket, there might be a problem.

Comment: @stribizhev It's markdown! So it comes with standards.

Comment: @stribizhev That's normal! Because you messed up the text with no reason and I can ruin your input as well.

Answer (score 1):

You can leverage the **discard technique** that it really useful for this cases. It consists of having below pattern:

```
patternToSkip1 (*SKIP)(*FAIL)|patternToSkip2 (*SKIP)(*FAIL)| MATCH THIS PATTERN
```

So, according you needs:

> to replace all the matches of a particular expression ((\W)(theWord)(\W)) all across the document EXCEPT the matches that are inside a markdown image syntax

You can easily achieve this in `pcre` through `(*SKIP)(*FAIL)` flags, so for you case you can use a regex like this:

```
\[.*?\](*SKIP)(*FAIL)|\bTheWord\b
```

Or using your pattern:

```
\[.*?\](*SKIP)(*FAIL)|(\W)(theWord)(\W)
```

The idea behind this regex is tell regex engine to skip the content within `[`...`]`

**[Working demo](https://regex101.com/r/vM9cL6/2)**

Comment: True, SKIP-FAIL is the correct trick for the 1st option. However, you should have used `\b` around `theWord` since the `(\W)` is redundant overhead.

Comment: @stribizhev FAIL is the easier-to-read alternative to a negative lookahead `(?!)` and not a magic

Comment: @stribizhev You said *SKIP-FAIL is the correct trick* and I mentioned it's nothing but an alternative.

Comment: @stribizhev Gosh I'm not comparing between alternatives and that's like those guys who can't stick with their girl friend: *-You know, she's a much better alternative.*

Comment: @stribizhev **Please avoid extended discussions in comments.** Okay SO, I just wanna say one more thing... don't rationalize!

Answer (score 0):

The first regex is easily fixed with a [SKIP-FAIL trick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24534782/how-do-skip-or-f-work-on-regex):

```
\!\[.*?\]\(http[^)]*\)(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|\bvitae\b
```

To replace with the word of your choice. It is a totally valid way in PHP (PCRE) regex to match something *outside* some markers.

See [Demo 1](https://regex101.com/r/fM2eZ6/7)

As for the second one, it is harder, but acheivable with [`\G`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21971701/when-is-g-useful-application-in-a-regex) that ensures we match *consecutively inside* some markers:

```
(\!\[.*?|(?<!^)\G)((?>(?!\]\(http).)*?){{([^}]+?)}}\[{2}[^]]+?\]{2}(?=.*?\]\(http[^)]*?\))
```

To replace with `$1$2{{NEW_REPLACED_TEXT}}[[NEW_DIGITS]]`

See [Demo 2](https://regex101.com/r/fM2eZ6/8)

PHP:

```
$re1 = "#\!\[.*?\]\(http[^)]*\)(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|\bvitae\b#i";
$re2 = "#(\!\[.*?|(?<!^)\G)((?>(?!\]\(http).)*?){{([^}]+?)}}\[{2}[^]]+?\]{2}(?=.*?\]\(http[^)]*?\))#i";
```

Comment: To be more accurate on patterns, to your second regex catastrophic backtracking is very likely to happen and I have a question: why atomic groups? Engine says *4 matches - 18720 steps*.  Don't you think that you are killing the performance by the way?

Comment: Once you come across catastrophic backtracking with this regex, please let me know. I am always more worried with accuracy and stability. What good is a quick regex that does not match what you need or overfire?

Comment: Like when there is a space between `] (`. Spaces are escaped within reserved symbols by the markdown parser and would you mind answering why you came with using atomic groups here?

Comment: Actually, the `](` *is* part of the markdown. If there are spaces between, they must be added into the pattern. The regex will not fail in case there are stray brackets inside the*text*, not *markdown*. Also, atomic groupings are useful when we are not interested in [backtracking positions remembered by any tokens inside the group](http://www.regular-expressions.info/atomic.html).

Comment: Forgetting backtracking positions - as I'm aware - is useful when you have multiple piped sequences inside the atomic group, and you don't have any. You're just checking a single expression at a time. So it's totally useless. Isn't it?

Comment: Tastes differ, like regex flavors. There is no difference here if I use a non-capturing group or atomic one.

Comment: Good night, I am off to bed

Comment: I got my answer! Good night!