# gsub: replace regex match with regex replacement string

Tags: regex, r, gsub

I have a requirement to replace more than 2 continuous 1's with equal number of zeros. Currently, I can find the match as below but I don't know how to replace with the exact number of zeros as the match is found

```
ind<-c(1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,0,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,0)
gsub("([1])\\1\\1+","0",paste0(ind,collapse=""))
```

gives

```
"11000001100011010010101000101000"
```

as it replaces the match with just one 0 but I need

```
"11000000001100011010010101000000010100000"
```

Comment: You begin with a vector, do you also want to end with a vector or a string?

Comment: @ColonelBeauvel either should be fine as I can convert between any.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following gsub replacement:

```
ind<-c(1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,0,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,0)
gsub("1(?=1{2,})|(?!^)\\G1","0",paste(ind,collapse=""), perl=T)
```

See [IDEONE demo](https://ideone.com/AVaKMw), the result is `[1] "11000000001100011010010101000000010100000"`.

The regex is Perl-based since it uses look-aheads and the `\G` operator.

This regex matches:

- `1` - a literal `1` if...
- `(?=1{2,})` - it is followed by 2 or more `1`s or...
- `(?!^)\\G1` - any `1` that is following the previous match.

For more details on the `\G` operator, see [*What good is \G in a regular expression?*](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq6.html#What-good-is-%5CG-in-a-regular-expression%3F) at perldoc.perl.org, and [*When is \G useful application in a regex?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21971701/when-is-g-useful-application-in-a-regex) SO post.

Comment: what if i want to do reverse. I want to replace sequence of 3 or less 1's with 0?

Comment: and could you tell me what to google for `\\G1`. I am seeing this for the first time

Comment: I added some links to the `\G` operator descriptions. When you need to replace sequences of 1 to 3 `1`s, you can use nested look-ahead with a look-behind to restrict the number of `1`s: [`(?<!1)1(?=1{1,2}(?!1))|(?!^)\\G1`](https://regex101.com/r/fK6nG1/1).

Answer (score 1):

A solution not using `regex` but `rle`:

```
x = rle(ind)
x$values[x$lengths>2 & x$values] <- 0
inverse.rle(x)

#[1] 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 1 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0
```