# Syntax for recursive regex in PHP

Tags: php, regex

I'm missing somethings that make me fail on using recursive (?R).

An example to explain my problem 'clearly':

```
$str1 = "somes text -start bla bla FIND bla bla bla FIND bla FIND bla end-";
$str2 = "somes text -start bla bla FIND bla bla bla FIND bla FIND bla end-";
$my_pattern = "-start .*(FIND).* end-";

preg_replace_callback($my_pattern, 'callback', $str1.$str2);
```

It will only match the very last FIND.

With the 'ungreedy' option i'll match the 1st FIND of both $str.

But how can i get all of them ? I tried to used '(?R)' but i dont really understand how it work.

Thank.

EDIT: The real work is to find all the 'title' property betweem `<a>` & `</a>`.
I know it's not optimise to use regex to parse html but it's just a work from school to learn regex.

That's why i didnt put the real work, i wanted to understand and be able to do it myself.

```
<html>
 <head><title>Nice page</title></head>
<body>
    Hello World
 <a href=http://cyan.com title="a link">
                this is a link
 </a>
<br />
<a href=http://www.riven.com> Here too <img src=wrong.image title="and again">
    <span>Even that<div title="same">all the same</div></span>
</a>
</body>
</html>
```

My job is too put every titles in uppercase (title="A LINK" for example) using regex.

My last pattern was:

```
#<a .* title=\"(.*)\".*</a>#Uis
```

Made me catch (title="a link") and (title="and again"). Your method should work (stribizhev) but i didnt succeed to implement it, i'm still on it.

Comment: what do you want? to get all the `FIND` or want to replace all `FIND`?

Comment: Several problems: Since pattern delimiters are missing, hyphens are seen as delimiters and not as literal characters. I think you confuse *repetition* and *recursion*, you don't need recursion here. You need to search about greedy quantifiers too. See the PHP manual and this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5319840/greedy-vs-reluctant-vs-possessive-quantifiers

Comment: @MubinKhalid : Yeah i want to replace them all using callback function.

to CasimiretHippolyte : Yeah forgot the delimiter on my example, i'm using '#' as delimiter.

Comment: You need a solution based on \G operator. I wish I could help but I'm on a mobile now. The regex would look like `(?:-start|(?!^)\G).*?(FIND)(?=.*end-)`. Instead of `.*`, you might need a tempered greedy token: `(?:(?!-start|end-|FIND).)*`. And even a sinleline flag `#s` at the end.

Comment: @stribizhev Hmm its seems to be right but i  dont understand your pattern very well... Could you please explain it steps by steps ? I'm not familliar with the \G operator

Comment: You can have a look at [When is \G useful application in a regex?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21971701/when-is-g-useful-application-in-a-regex) and [What good is \G in a regular expression?](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq6.html#What-good-is-%5cG-in-a-regular-expression%3f).

Comment: @stribizhev i'll check thoses links, could u pls explain steps by steps too ?

Comment: @stribizhev edit with the real exercice, thank you for your help.

Comment: @Mickael_42: You must be kidding: your job is to manipulate HTML code, and you selected regex? That way you will end up with even more headache when you have to modify anything. I will just update with a proper way using DOMDocument.

Comment: @stribizhev i didnt selected regex... i have to do it using regex, its not my call.

Answer (score 1):

## UPDATED ANSWER - CHANGING CASE IN HTML

You need to use DOMDocument with DOMXPath to safely get all title attributes and change them with [`mb_strtoupper`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-strtoupper.php):

```
$html = "<<YOUR_HTML>>";
$dom = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'UTF-8');
$dom->loadHTML($html, LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED | LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD);

$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
$titles = $xpath->query('//a[@title]');

foreach($titles as $title) { 
   $title->setAttribute("title", mb_strtoupper($title->getAttribute("title"), 'UTF-8'));
}

echo $dom->saveHTML();
```

See [IDEONE demo](http://ideone.com/XZZAxU).

The `//a[@title]` xpath gets `<a>` elements (`a`) with an attribute `title`.

I use `mb_strtoupper` assuming you have UTF8 input. Please adjust accordingly, or if you are not planning to use Unicode, just use [`strtoupper`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtoupper.php).

## ORIGINAL ANSWER BEFORE UPDATE

Here is a regex that will let you replace all `FIND` substrings inside the `-start` and `-end`:

```
(-start|(?!^)\G)(.*?)FIND(?=.*end-)
```

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/xU0qO6/1)

Replace with `$1$2NEW_WORD`.

[PHP code](http://ideone.com/30BGZt):

```
$re = "#(-start|(?!^)\G)(.*?)FIND(?=.*end-)#"; 
$str = "somes text -start bla bla FIND bla bla bla FIND bla FIND bla end-"; 
$subst = "$1$2NEW_WORD"; 
$result = preg_replace($re, $subst, $str);
echo $result;
```

**NOTE**: If you have several `start-end` blocks, you will most probably need a tempered greedy token `(?:(?!-start|end-|FIND).)*` instead of `.*?` and `.*`.

The regex breakdown:

- `(-start|(?!^)\G)` - This group contains two alternatives:

  - `-start` - matches the literal string `-start`
  - `(?!^)\G` - asserts the position in the original input string right after the last successful match. `\G` can also assert the beginning of the string, but we exclude it with the negative look-ahead.
- `(.*?)` - Match any number of characters but as few as possible
- `FIND` - literal string `FIND`
- `(?=.*end-)` - only if there is literal string `end-` after the `FIND`.

For more information on `\G` operator, see [When is \G useful application in a regex?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21971701/when-is-g-useful-application-in-a-regex) and [What good is \G in a regular expression?](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq6.html#What-good-is-%5cG-in-a-regular-expression%3f).

Comment: Could you please explain to me how this "|(?!^)\G)" works pls ?

Comment: `\G` asserts the position at the beginning of the string (as `^`) or the end of the last successful match. That means, it enforces all multiple matches  to be consecutive in the input string. The negative lookahead before `\G` restricts it to match just consecutive matches. Since `-start` is the first alternative in the first group, it is checked for first. If a match is found (i.e. `somethingFIND`) then all consecutive matches (anything after the first `FIND` and again `FIND`) are matched.

Comment: i do not succeed to adapt it on my work... i'm missing somethings :x

Comment: Just as a [bonus](http://ideone.com/PXSYYU) for you. But do not use it: with large pages this will lead to catastrophic backtracking one day.

Comment: Please check this updated code with [`'/(<a\s+[^<]*\btitle=")([^"<]*)(?="[^<]*>)/i'`](http://ideone.com/PXSYYU). I will delete it, and you must delete the "school" comment.

Comment: ok i'll looking on it and try to understand it. Thank you very much

Comment: your code doesn't match all (title=""), but only the 1st one like i do.

Comment: What is you requirement? You yourself said you needed to replace `title` attribute values with uppercase texts in `<a>` tags only, and now you wish to also modify `title` attributes in `img`, `div` and any other tags? Please be specific. If you need a regex that will match `title` attribute in all tags, just remove `a\s+` from the one above.

Answer (score 0):

If using `preg_replace_callback` why wouldn't [reluctant](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5319978) `.*?` be convenient.

```
$my_pattern = "/-start(.*?)end-/s";

$str = preg_replace_callback($my_pattern, function($matches) {
  return str_replace("FIND", "<b>FIND</b>", $matches[0]);
}, $str1.$str2);
```

Or do something else in callback. What are you trying to achieve?