# How to perform search-and-replace within given $start-$end ranges?

Tags: regex, perl, replace

Say, a text file have many `$start-$end` pairs, and within each pair there are some text. I want Perl to find-and-replace all `$pattern`s with the `$start-$end` pairs; if the `$pattern` lies out of the pair, then don't replace it. eg for text:

```
xx START xx bingo xx bingo xx END xx bingo xx START xx bingo xx END bingo
```

There might be newlines anywhere in the text (not shown here); `$pattern` may appear multiple times within a pair. Expected result is:

```
xx START xx okyes xx okyes xx END xx bingo xx START xx okyes xx END bingo
```

The job seems straightforward but I just do not figure out a Perl regex to do it. Can anyone help with this?

Comment: Are your patterns always single words?

Comment: Lazy quantifier: [`(?:START)(.+?)(?:END)`](https://regex101.com/r/aG6qD9/1) - and search for / replace bingo in `$1`. Though a more realisitc input might be helpful, especially with newlines, etc.

Comment: [`s/(?:START|(?!^)\G)(?:(?!START|END).)*?\Kbingo/okyes/g`](https://regex101.com/r/lS7qJ1/1).

Comment: @Sobrique For the time being, yes, it should be just single words.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Yes! I don't understand the intimidating regex, but it does work!! I think I'll study this expression very, very carefully.

Comment: @katyusza: Sorry, I can't post that here. If you need to study the regex, look for a [tempered greedy token](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-quantifiers.html#tempered_greed) , [`\K`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13542950/support-of-k-in-regex), [`\G`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21971701/when-is-g-useful-application-in-a-regex). Note that it is not the fastest solution.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Got that;-) you already did me a great favor. I'm currently doing ad-hoc Perl stuff; execution speed is the least priority for me.

Comment: That should probably be posted as an answer rather than a comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually used following code to accomplish what I intended:

```
$_ = "xx START xx bingo xx bingo xx END xx bingo xx START xx bingo xx END bingo";
print;
print "\n";
$_ =~ s/START.*?END/($s=$&) =~ s,bingo,okyes,g; $s/ge;
print;
```

This is a one-regex solution, using embedded expression in `s///g` regex, and nested `s///g` regexes.

Sorry for this late post, but I deeply appreciate the replies by @Sobrique, @Borodin and @choroba, which are enlightening and helpful.

Answer (score 3):

Looking at your 'source' I would suggest the trick here is to set `$/` - the record separator.

If you set it to a single space, you can iterate word by word. 
And then use a [range operator](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Range-Operators) to determine if you're within delimiters.

Example:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

local $/ = ' ';

while ( <DATA> ) {
   if (  m/START/ .. /END/ ) {
       s/bingo/okyes/g;
   } 
   print;
}

__DATA__
xx START xx bingo xx bingo xx END xx bingo xx START xx bingo xx END bingo
```

This prints:

```
xx START xx okyes xx okyes xx END xx bingo xx START xx okyes xx END bingo
```

You could probably accomplish this with a single regex. I'm going to suggest that you *don't* because it'll quite complicated and hard to understand later.

Comment: I was just hacking on the range operator solution as well. :)

Answer (score 2):

I find things like this are most simply done using the `@-` and `@+` built-in arrays in conjunction with `substr` as an lvalue

`$-[1]` contains the offset within the string where the first capture began, while `$+[1]` contains the offset where it ended. Hence `$+[1]-$-[1]` is the length of the captured section

This program finds all occurrences of `/START(.+?)END/` and edits the captured section -- the region between `START` and `END` -- by applying a regex substitution to that substring

You may need to chnage this slightly depending on the real-world data that you're working with

```
use strict;
use warnings 'all';
use feature 'say';

my $str = 'xx START xx bingo xx bingo xx END xx bingo xx START xx bingo xx END bingo';
my ($start, $end, $pattern, $replacement) = qw/ START END bingo okyes /;

while ( $str =~ /\b$start\b(.+?)\b$end\b/gs ) {
     substr($str, $-[1], $+[1]-$-[1]) =~ s/$pattern/$replacement/g;
}

say $str;
```

#### output

```
xx START xx okyes xx okyes xx END xx bingo xx START xx okyes xx END bingo
```

Answer (score 1):

Split each line on START on END, keep a flag that tells you whether you are inside a range or not.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

my $inside;
while (<>) {
    my @strings = split /(START|END)/;
    for my $string (@strings) {
        if ('START' eq $string) {
            $inside = 1;

        } elsif ('END' eq $string) {
            undef $inside;

        } elsif ($inside) {
            $string =~ s/bingo/okyes/g;

        }

        print $string;
    }
}
```

Or a bit shorter using a hash as a switch:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use Syntax::Construct qw{ // };

my $inside;
while (<>) {
    my @strings = split /(START|END)/;
    for my $string (@strings) {
        $inside = { START => 1,
                    END   => 0,
                  }->{$string} // $inside;

        $string =~ s/bingo/okyes/g if $inside;
        print $string;
    }
}
```