# Regex multiline match first part of lines between two strings

Tags: regex, autohotkey

I have only a crude understanding of RegEx and I'm stumped!

My file is formatted like this:

```
>>  

    www.google.com  some stuff I don't want
    www.yahoo.com

<<section>>

    www.bing.com
    www.yahoo.com

<<section>>

    www.bing.com
    https://github.com/zeeshanu/learn-regex
```

Here are the conditions I am hoping to match:

- only the lines after the first ">>" and before the first "<<" on it
- select only first block of text on each line, no text following whitespace after first text
- ignore any initial white space on line if any

I have been able make this regex to select the part of the line I want:

```
^([^>>]\s*\S*){1}
```

But I can't get it to work within the proper strings.

Comment: So basically you just want the URLs? Do they always consist of only lowercase letters and dots? If you can narrow down what you're looking for a bit more, this might have a rather simple solution. Regarding your current pattern, `[^>>]` is a negated character class. Including `>` twice is redundant. The quantifier `{1}` is also redundant, as all characters/groups are implicitly quantified once unless otherwise indicated.

Comment: Anyway, this might be all you need, at least according to the example you posted: `[a-z]+\.[a-z.]+`

Comment: You could always use this `^\h*\K[^\s]+(?=.*$[\s\S]*<<)` and then ensure the first capture group matches `^(?:<<\w+)?>>\h*$`. Unfortunately, regex doesn't support quantifiers in lookbehinds, otherwise you could do that. The only other option I can think of is to use some sort of code capsule to ensure that somewhere before it a `>>`. See http://www.rexegg.com/regex-disambiguation.html#codecapsule for more info

Comment: Yes I just want the urls, but they could be any url. ctwheels expression worked, but if there were more double brackets, it selected beyond the first occurrance: https://regex101.com/r/e9dKzo/3

Comment: Try [`(?:\G(?!\A).*\R(?!\h*<<)\h*|>>\s*)\K\S+`](https://regex101.com/r/gGFenL/2)

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew thanks, this works but can it stop at the first <<section>>? so it only captures the first group of urls? https://regex101.com/r/e9dKzo/5

Comment: Is [`<<SECTION>>[\s\S]*\z(*SKIP)(*F)|(?:\G(?!\A).*\R\h*|^>>\s*)\K\S+`](https://regex101.com/r/e9dKzo/6) doing what you need?

Comment: Yes! thanks Wiktor I would never have been able to figure that out

Comment: Thanks for deconstructing my mistakes @CAustin, That makes sense it guess I was way off!

Comment: @jakejake Posted as an answer, please consider accepting.

Comment: @ctwheels There is no need using code here, just `\G` operator comes handy here.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thanks! I knew there was a reset token somewhere but couldn't find it in the documentation. I'll keep `\G` in mind for future regex.

Comment: @ctwheels You may check [Regexp Quote-Like Operators](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Regexp-Quote-Like-Operators), scroll to `\G assertion`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use

```
(?:\G(?!\A).*\R\h*|^>>\s*)\K\S+
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/HWYMRd/2). You will most probably want to pass `i` modifier to make the pattern match in a case insensitive way.

**Details**

- `(?:\G(?!\A).*\R\h*|^>>\s*)` - match the end of the previous match (`\G(?!\A)`) and then any 0+ chars other than line break chars, as many as possible (`.*`), then a line break (`\R`) and then any 0+ horizontal whitespaces (`\h*`), or (`|`) a `>>` substring at the start of the line and then 0+ whitespaces (`\s*`)
- `\K` - omit the text matched so far
- `\S+` - and match and return just 1 or more chars other than whitespace.

Comment: could you explain why "<<section>>[\s\S]*\z(*SKIP)(*F)" is needed? I took it out and it seems to work the same.

Comment: Ok, you may omit that part.

Comment: Some more reference links: [*`\K` match reset* operator](https://www.regular-expressions.info/keep.html) and [*`\G` operator*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21971701/when-is-g-useful-application-in-a-regex).