# reformat list string with spaces

Tags: regex, perl, awk

I have a string list that is printed to the console. I need to convert back it to quoted string.

Assume the sample file is like below

```
List(UT_LVL_17_CD, UT_LVL_20_CD, 2018 1Q, 2018 2Q, 2018 3Q, 2018 4Q, 2018 FY)
List(UT_LVL_17_CD,UT_LVL_20_CD,2018 1Q,2018 2Q,018 3Q,2018 4Q,2018 FY)
List( UT_LVL_17_CD,    UT_LVL_20_CD,2018 1Q,2018 2Q, 2018 3Q, 2018 4Q, 2018 FY )
```

For all the 3 combinations above, the output should be

```
List("UT_LVL_17_CD", "UT_LVL_20_CD", "2018 1Q", "2018 2Q", "2018 3Q", "2018 4Q", "2018 FY")
```

note that spaces at the start, end or between elements is acceptable.

```
List(  "UT_LVL_17_CD", "UT_LVL_20_CD", "2018 1Q", "2018 2Q", "2018 3Q", "2018 4Q",    "2018 FY" )
```

but not within the string value, like below

```
"     UT_LVL_17_CD"
"UT_LVL_20_CD   ",
```

the spaces that are already in each element should be preserved `"2018 4Q"`

I'm trying something like below, but not able to get the correct result.

```
$ perl -pe ' s/(?<=\()|(?=,)|(?=\))/\"/sg ' list.txt
List("UT_LVL_17_CD", UT_LVL_20_CD", 2018 1Q", 2018 2Q", 2018 3Q", 2018 4Q", 2018 FY")
List("UT_LVL_17_CD",UT_LVL_20_CD",2018 1Q",2018 2Q",018 3Q",2018 4Q",2018 FY")
List(" UT_LVL_17_CD",    UT_LVL_20_CD",2018 1Q",2018 2Q", 2018 3Q", 2018 4Q", 2018 FY ")
$
```

Comment: Same idea: [`(?<=[\(,])\s*(.*?)\s*(?=[,\)])`](https://regex101.com/r/pvIqff/2)

Comment: @JvdV.. yes it works.. can you add it as answer

Comment: @JvdV.. it is just a scratch work.. performance is not a concern..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See if the following works for you:

```
[(,]\K\s*(.*?)\s*(?=[),])
```

See the online [demo](https://regex101.com/r/ouoMeM/2)

---

- `[(,]` - Match a comma or opening paranthesis.
- `\K` - Reset starting point of reported match.
- `\s*` - Match zero or more spaces.
- `(.*?)` - 1st Capture group to capture any character with lazy quantifier.
- `\s*` - Match zero or more spaces.
- `(?=[),])` - Positive lookahead to match a comma or closing paranthesis.

As per the linked demo, replace with `"\1"`.

Answer (score 3):

```
perl -wpe'
    s{ \(\K ([^)]+) }
     { join ", ", map { s/^\s+|\s+$//g; qq("$_") } split /,/, $1 }ex
' file
```

Comment: the last value is appearing as ````"2018 FY "```` it should be ````"2018 FY"````

Comment: @stack0114106 Fixed.  Can't see anything nicer than simply stripping leading/trailing spaces inside `map`, will look again a little later...

Comment: np.. have a nice day

Comment: Edit: Have to strip trailing space in the `map` -- but then can get all cleaned out, so removed other `\s`

Answer (score 2):

Another option could be using the `\G` anchor and match word characters optionally repeated by spaces and word characters.

```
(?:\G(?!^),|\bList\((?=[^()\r\n]*\)))\K\h*(\w+(?:\h+\w+)*)\h*
```

**Explanation**

- `(?:` Non capture group

  - `\G(?!^),` Assert the position at the end of the previous match, but not at the start (as `\G` can match at those 2 positions)
  - `|` Or
  - `\bList\((?=[^()\r\n]*\))` Word boundary, then match `List(` and assert a closing `)` on the same line
- `)` Close non capture group
- `\K\h*` Forget what is matched so far (to not remove the matched `List(` and the comma's) and match optional spaces to be removed
- `(` Capture **group 1**

  - `\w+(?:\h+\w+)*` Match 1+ word chars optionally repeated by spaces and word chars
- `)\h*` Close group 1 and match optional trailing spaces to be removed

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/AYnaTP/1)

In the replacement use group 1 between double quotes `"\1"`

Comment: yes.. it works.. but finding it difficult to understand

Comment: do you have any other simple examples for understanding the \G in regex

Comment: @stack0114106 You can see for example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21971701/when-is-g-useful-application-in-a-regex or  http://www.rexegg.com/regex-anchors.html#G) or[https://www.regular-expressions.info/continue.html

Comment: I tried in the \G style for this question.. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65435848/concatenating-hierarchical-paths-from-the-root#65436025 can you have a look at it

Answer (score 2):

OP mentions that leading/trailing spaces are acceptable ... I take this to mean that it's also acceptable to strip out unnecessary leading/trailing spaces.

Sample input:

```
$ cat string.dat
List(UT_LVL_17_CD, UT_LVL_20_CD, 2018 1Q, 2018 2Q, 2018 3Q, 2018 4Q, 2018 FY)
List(UT_LVL_17_CD,UT_LVL_20_CD,2018 1Q,2018 2Q,018 3Q,2018 4Q,2018 FY)
List( UT_LVL_17_CD,    UT_LVL_20_CD,2018 1Q,2018 2Q, 2018 3Q, 2018 4Q, 2018 FY )
```

One not-so-compact `awk` idea:

```
awk -F'[()]' '                         # input field delimiters are "(" and ")"
{ printf "%s(", $1                     # print field #1 + "("
  n=split($2,a,",")                    # split field #2 by ",", save in array a[]
  pfx=""                               # initial prefix is ""
  for (i=1 ; i<=n ; i++)               # loop through a[] elements
      { gsub(/^ *| *$/,"",a[i])        # strip leading/trailing spaces
        printf "%s\"%s\"", pfx, a[i]   # print prefix + current a[] element wrapped in double quotes
        pfx=","                        # set prefix to "," for rest of a[] elements
      }
   printf ")\n"                        # print final ")"
}
' string.dat
```

This generates:

```
List("UT_LVL_17_CD","UT_LVL_20_CD","2018 1Q","2018 2Q","2018 3Q","2018 4Q","2018 FY")
List("UT_LVL_17_CD","UT_LVL_20_CD","2018 1Q","2018 2Q","018 3Q","2018 4Q","2018 FY")
List("UT_LVL_17_CD","UT_LVL_20_CD","2018 1Q","2018 2Q","2018 3Q","2018 4Q","2018 FY")
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
(?<=\(|,)\s*(.*?)\s*(?=\)|,)
```

by this regex u can match every text with group that not contain space at start and at the end then append to it ""
[look at demo](https://regex101.com/r/jZZrnG/1)

Answer (score 1):

Yet another variant:

```
$ perl -pne 's/\(\s+/\(/; /([^(]+\()(.+)\)/; $_="$1\"".join("\",\"",split(/,\s*/,$2)).")\n"; ' file
List("UT_LVL_17_CD","UT_LVL_20_CD","2018 1Q","2018 2Q","2018 3Q","2018 4Q","2018 FY)
List("UT_LVL_17_CD","UT_LVL_20_CD","2018 1Q","2018 2Q","018     3Q","2018 4Q","2018 FY)
List("UT_LVL_17_CD","UT_LVL_20_CD","2018 1Q","2018 2Q","2018 3Q","2018 4Q","2018 FY )
```

Input test file:

```
$ cat file
List(UT_LVL_17_CD, UT_LVL_20_CD, 2018 1Q, 2018 2Q, 2018 3Q, 2018 4Q, 2018 FY)
List(UT_LVL_17_CD,    UT_LVL_20_CD,2018 1Q,2018 2Q,018     3Q,2018 4Q,2018 FY)
List( UT_LVL_17_CD,    UT_LVL_20_CD,2018 1Q,2018 2Q, 2018 3Q, 2018 4Q, 2018 FY )
```

Comment: great..idea.. splitting on ````/,\s*/```` after initial cleansing..